# Django - __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, http-headers

I am trying to download a CSV when a button is clicked, however, I am getting the error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers
```

this is my view:

```
def download_file(request):
    response = HttpResponse(
        content_type='text/csv',
        headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'},
    )
    return response
```

this is the trackback:

```
Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/matthewkaye/Eflux/Argus/app/views.py" in download_file
  74.     response = HttpResponse(

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/http/response.py" in __init__
  289.         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /Download
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'
```

Comment: What Django version are you using `import django; print(django.VERSION)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using an older Django version. In version 2, it is not possible to set the headers in the constructor. Try

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
```

See also [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.**init**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__init__)

Comment: thanks @Leonard ! that solved the request error however it is downloading a bank csv with the name of my file path , how do I get it to download the specified file I want rather than it creating one?

Comment: You have to set the content: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment .of the HttpResponse.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain ! how would you do that in this context? when I set the content to the file location it just sets the content of the csv to the file path string.

Comment: Yeah, you have to open that file and return the byte string. 

Something like `f = open('myfilename.csv', 'r'); content = f.read(); response = HttpResponse(content=content, ...)`.